# Docker patch command substitution

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am using a Docker image and it comes with many binaries from busybox.
I need the command "patch" to accept the param "-l". But the command that comes with busybox won't allow this param and it will break giving the following exception:

```
/usr/local # patch -l
patch: unrecognized option: l
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: patch [OPTIONS] [ORIGFILE [PATCHFILE]]

-p N    Strip N leading components from file names
-i DIFF Read DIFF instead of stdin
-R  Reverse patch
-N  Ignore already applied patches
-E  Remove output files if they become empty
--dry-run   Don't actually change files
```

Is there any way to substitute the patch command for another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to substitute the patch command for another one?

Sure, but the mechanism for doing that is going to vary depending on which image you're using.

If you're using an [Alpine](https://www.alpinelinux.org/) based image, you can just do this:

```
apk add --update patch
```

This will replace the BusyBox version of `patch` with the full-featured GNU `patch` binary.

If you're using something else...you'll need to provide additional details in your question.